# ASP.NET MVC rendering model not the way I expect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Today I faced a problem and I'm not able to get weather I understand something wrong about ASP.NET MVC (and possibly MVC in general) or I miss something about it's implementation.

So, I have a simple model hierarchy:

```
public class Child
{
    public Child(int notId, bool isSelected, string text)
    {
        NotId = notId;
        IsSelected = isSelected;
        Text = text;
    }

    public Child(){}

    // naming: just to make sure I do not mess with some
    // conventional infrastructure
    public int NotId { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } 
}
```

Here is my `HomeController`'s Edit actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    var parent = new Parent
                    {
                        Children = new List<Child>
                                {
                                    new Child(1, true, "a"),
                                    new Child(2, false, "b")
                                }
                    };
    return View(parent);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Parent parent)
{
    parent.Children = new List<Child>
                        {
                            new Child(4, false, "c"),
                            new Child(5, true, "d")
                        };
    return View(parent);
}
```

Hese is my `Edit.aspx` view:

```
<!-- Standart HTML elements ommited --> 
<% Html.BeginForm(); %>
<% for (var i = 0; i < Model.Children.Count; i++){%>
<div>
    <%=Html.LabelFor(m => m.Children[i].IsSelected)%>
    <%=Html.EditorFor(m => m.Children[i].IsSelected)%> <!-- lamda -->
    <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Children[i].IsSelected)%> <!-- lamda -->
    <%=Html.CheckBox("A", Model.Children[i].IsSelected)%> <!-- simple -->
</div>
<% } %>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<% Html.EndForm();%>
```

The point is that in `Edit` (HttpGet) method I create `Parent` instance with two child `Child` elements having their `IsSelected` properties set to `true` and `false` respectively. After form is submitted in `Edit` (HttpPost) method I give my `Parent` object a new children collection of two `Child` elements with their `IsSelected` properties set to `false` and `true` respectively (that is opposite from HttpGet method) and call `View()` method to render my model.

But what I get after submit is checkboxes, rendered with `Html.EditorFor()` and `Html.CheckBoxFor()` do not changes their state. It looks like `Html.EditorFor()` and `Html.CheckBoxFor()` methods take data *NOT* from my model but from a posted form data.

Could someone please explain me what is going on here and why ASP.NET MVC refuses to render my model? Workarounds? Fixes to my code?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I noticed this behavior in MVC2 and thought this was some kind of a bug, but when I tested this with MVC3 it did the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Html.CheckBoxFor() methods take data NOT from my model but from a
>   posted form data.

That is correct.

You'll have to clear ModelState with `ModelState.Clear()` to get these checkboxes to use the actual Model value and not the form data.

Answer (score 2):

> But what I get after submit is checkboxes, rendered with
>   Html.EditorFor() and Html.CheckBoxFor() do not changes their state. It
>   looks like Html.EditorFor() and Html.CheckBoxFor() methods take data
>   NOT from my model but from a posted form data.

That's exactly what they do and that's by design. Html helpers first look at modelstate when binding values and then the model. If you want to change this behavior you could remove all the items from model state that you intend to modify in your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Parent parent)
{
    ModelState.Remove("Children");
    parent.Children = new List<Child>
    {
        new Child(4, false, "c"),
        new Child(5, true, "d")
    };
    return View(parent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was missing something :)